# How to extract the database file when using SQLExpress in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, sql-server-2005, deployment

I have made my database in SQLExpress and its a **master** database . I would like to create a CD for my project so need the database file. I am not able to find that file please suggest a solution 
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need the .mdf and .ldf in the SQL Server installation directory, but if you've created everything in the master database, I'd recommend creating a different database and moving everything there instead. The master db shouldn't be used for stuff like that.

Comment: how do i copy all my data from the master database to another database?

Answer (score 3):

Your database files would be in the `App_Data` folder by default if you are using SQL-Express provided with Visual Studio.

You can generate an SQL script of your database which can be used to re-create it in different db server by running the script again. For this right-click on the database in the `Server Explorer` and select `Publish to Provider`.

Comment: they arent there because am using a master db not an mdf file ! i have a lot of tables to create a database again please help!

Comment: @vini Then it would be better if you generate the sql script file for your database and use it for re-creating the database. Check edited answer....

Comment: yup have created an sql script ! how do i use it in a new database if i create it using an mdf file

Comment: @vini Create a new database with some name. Now delete the create database definition from the sql script file. Rest copy all the remaining script in the query editor in SQL Server Management Studio or in Visual Studio query editor whereever you have made the database. Run the query and your database will be filled with the tables.

Comment: @vini Delete all the GO words. Find & Replace :P